# Is there a way to specify the width & height of a `ShapeDrawable` in xml?

Tags: android-drawable, shapedrawable, layer-list

Android: Is there a way to specify the width & height of a `ShapeDrawable` in xml? This seems surprisingly difficult.  Using the `<size>` child of  does not work, nor does wrapping the `<shape>` in a layer list item and setting `android:height` and `android:weight` attributes.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- 
How do you set shape size?
The top/bottom attributes allow setting size via an inset
from the parent element, but isn't there way to explicitly
set width and height???
-->
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#f00" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#0f0" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

`size` and `padding` tags always available under `shape` tag. Please recheck your code.

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <size android:height="4dp" android:width="15dp" />
        <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```